# Mikrotik Usermanager giving incorrect data transfer

Tags: mikrotik-routeros, mikrotik-swos

i have a problem when i set limitation for a profile in the usermanager for mikrotik, the limit ion wont work because the download and upload is taking too long to reach the transfer limit. eg a transfer limit of 5MB might run forever. what could be the problem? Thanks for your help.